# Is there a better way to prevent other device access to IPv6/IPv4:80 on network?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

There are two device A and B.

Usually, only use 10.0.0.1 to access their webpage, but I found that I can use IPv6 or IPv4 with port 80 to access device-B's webpage on device-A.

```
example. http://[IPv6-B]:80
```

So, I check the iptables, and there is no rule to prevent it.

Configuring iptables might be a good way, but I still search for how to use it.

Is any better way to set firewall settings or prevent access to network services from WAN interface?

Comment: Note: you have ip6tables for IPV6 addresses (it should be parallel to the other, but with few differences: no need to block fragments [IPv6 doesn't allow them], and the IP addresses are different.

Comment: Yes, IP addresses are different and two device it not in same place.  It is kind of security concern.  so, that's why I  would like to set the firewall config.

Comment: What security concern do you have with connections using IPv6? There are several higher level firewall configuration tools, e.g. shorewall, ufw, ipcop, ... These might be easier to setup than pure ip(6)tables.

Comment: Depending on which web server you're running you can probably set it to listen only on `10.0.0.1`. This would block the WAN interface and all IPv6 connections.

Comment: In this case, if I got device A global IPV6 address, then I have a chance to use device-B and enter http;//[IPV6-A];80  to access device-A webpage and change setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `firewalld` or `ufw`, rules will be applied to both IPv4 and IPv6. You will not have to handle them separately.

`ufw` might be simpler and easier to learn.

`firewalld` runs a process which uses some megabytes of RAM.  So `ufw` is good for very limited systems.

`firewalld` is useful if you want to be able to manage it using a configuration file, as opposed to running commands or using a graphical app.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
ip6tables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```